# Failed to connect to remote VM

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, connection-refused

I configure tomcat to debug remotely from Eclipse:

start "Configure Tomcat". Go to Java tab. add the following line:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

Then start the server.

But I don't see no one log in catalina.out referring to JPDA!
Also I don't see that port 8000 is listening (using `netstat -a`).

I get the following error when I try to debug from eclipse (using remote debug settings):

> Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused

Why?

Comment: Only for debugging purpose, here are two ideas: 1, change the port and switch of the firewall (if you have any), 2, add something new to your config after the JPDA configuration, for example extremely low Xms/Xmx settings, to see that the Tomcat read your parameters correctly.

Comment: 1) I tried to use another port (1044).
2) I allowed all in my firewall, that connected with java and tomcat
3) I add some new config (Xms/Xmx) into Tomcat java option and it doesn't start, so before were correct options and tomcat read it fine.
But I still have this error :(

Comment: Woww, now it works fine. I've just changed the config on that I used before. But I still cannot understand why didn't it work....Is it magic??:)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8 :)

Comment: very nice :) I think my web app didn't start when I tried to debug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 8000 is free? or is it being used by some one else?

Comment: I think it is free, because it isn't in netstat list

Comment: Also you may want to use 127.0.0.1 for host to avoid any host entry conflicts.